# Generate Test from Protractor Interactive Mode Input

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, interactive, angularjs-e2e

I have watched this video https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-protractor-interactive and I'm wondering about the following question. Is it possible, to copy the commands, that I typed during testing in the protractor interactive mode, into the clipboard? It would be nice, because I could paste it into a test and add my expectations.